# Quickest way to check GORM validity

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a legacy database which I am trying to write a GORM for. I can't update it.  I making best guesses at what  way I can write the GORM objects and then start up with validation mode equal to true.

Just wondering is there a quicker way to do this - as in can I check it without having a full start up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you already have the quickest (and only) way to check a domain class validity for mapping via GORM.

Unless of course you don't mind doing verification by hand. In which case you could use the [database migration plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) to output the migration for the domain class and compare it to the schema of your legacy database or use [database reverse engineering plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer) to reverse engineer domain classes from the legacy database.